# Call form method after other form action

Tags: vb.net

I got some problem. I have mdi forms in my application i have first form where i am using button click. I would like if this button was clicked my second form (if its opened) raise its method. Note that second form is not a child of first (then i would pass to its constructor) but here they are separated. How to do that? What i tried so far is:

First Form:

```
Public Class FrmFirst

    Public Event Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Public Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Some code...
            RaiseEvent Start(Me, e)  'raise event
    End Sub
```

Second form:

```
Public Class FrmSecond

'Static
    Public WithEvents MySender As FrmFirst

'method which should be executed
 Public Sub alejaja(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MySender.Start
        ReloadGrid()
End Sub
```

Update:

FrmFirst could be opened from toolsstrip label:

```
  Private Sub ToolStripLabelFrmFirst _Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripLabelFrmFirst.Click
        Dim First As New FrmFirst 
            First.MdiParent = Me
            First.Show()
    End Sub
```

FrmSecond could be opened from other toolsstriplabel same way:

```
   Private Sub ToolStripLabelFrmSecond_Click(sender As System.Object, e
As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripLabelFrmSecond.Click
         Dim Second As New FrmSecond()
             Second.MdiParent = Me
             Second.Show()
     End Sub
```

Comment: What did you get out of this code? The structure seems Ok.

Comment: Nothing second form ReloadGrid is not executing

Comment: Are you sure MySender is the form that is shown as FrmFirst? I'm talking about the referenced object

Comment: Yes FrmFirst is the class when i am doing btnAdd_Click

Comment: Note that FrmFirst and FrmSecond are separated forms i am not passing anything via contructors. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Can you show me the code that creates FrmFirst and assigns it to `MySender`?

Comment: i made update in main topic for you.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I meant: you create a new `FrmFirst`, but `MySender` member inside `FrmSecond` is totally another thing and has nothing to do with this instance. If I did clarify the problem for you, let's find a solution :)

Comment: i mentioned that in first post that FrmSecond is not a child or any constructor parameter is not passing from FrmFirst to FrmSecond. They are commpletly separated because its not required that FrmFirst has to be opened before FrmSecond. And i am seeking how to resolve that If FrmSecond is opened and inside FrmFirst someone click add then Frm Second method will be called.

Comment: Is it Ok to make them singletons?

Comment: i see what you want to achieve is they would have only one instance instead of creating new .. then my first solution would work right? I dont want to have that way because those forms could be opened multiple times. So creating new instances of both are required.

Comment: Very good. Now what you want seems to be a Publisher/Subscriber model. You can create another object (or use your main form) to receive the events from instances of `FrmFirst` and dispatch them to all instances of `FrmSecond`.

Comment: And pardon me for answering step-by-step. I just want to make sure you get the right answer

Comment: could you please bring your idea according to my code how can i implement that?

Comment: I am writing the complete answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a 'hub' for the events which receives events from FrmFirst instances and dispatches them to `FrmSecond` instances. We can use the main form because it has a reference inside both classes.

In your main form, add a `Start` event and handle `Start` event for each `FrmFirst` instance you create:

```
Public Event Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

' Start events raised from every FrmFirst instance will invoke this method
Private Sub First_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ' And this will invoke every FrmSecond instance's event handlers
    RaiseEvent Start(sender, e)
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripLabelFrmFirst _Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripLabelFrmFirst.Click
    Dim First As New FrmFirst 
    First.MdiParent = Me
    AddHandler First.Start , AddressOf First_Start
    First.Show()
End Sub
```

Then add a handler to this new event when creating an `FrmSecond` instance:

```
Private Sub ToolStripLabelFrmSecond_Click(sender As System.Object, _
             e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripLabelFrmSecond.Click
     Dim Second As New FrmSecond()
     Second.MdiParent = Me
     AddHandler Me.Start, AddressOf Second.alejaja ' This will make the object receive Start events from FrmMain

     Second.Show()
End Sub
```

Of course you should use a RemoveHandler on `Closed` event of the Forms to prevent memory leaks. This is the way inside `FrmSecond`:

```
Private Sub Form_Closed(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Closed

    ' Replace Form1 with your Mdi parent form's class name
    RemoveHandler CType(Me.MdiParent, Form1).Start, AddressOf Me.alejaja 
End Sub
```

Comment: by the way when we need to use WithEvents? its not required here?

Comment: @StackUser `WithEvents` and `Handles` are VB.NET's shortcuts which can be used instead of .NET's standard `AddHandler` (event+=delegate in C#). When you mark a Field with `WithEvents`, VB.NET creates a wrapper property for the field and in its setter adds a call to `AddHandler` for each `Handles` clause placed on a method. It is just simpler, but makes the compiled code more complex.

Comment: Another reason would be backward compatibility with VB's syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your *MySender* variable is always Nothing, you never initialize it.  So it isn't going to detect any events either.  You are violating a design pattern here, one form class ought to not have to know anything about another one.  Except for your MDI parent class, it necessary needs to know about all of them since it creates instances of them.

Start fixing this by making the ReloadGrid() method public.  In your MDI parent form, write code that keeps track of the lifetime of FrmFirst so you can properly update it when necessary.  Like this:

```
Private FrmFirst First;

Private Sub ToolStripLabelFrmFirst _Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripLabelFrmFirst.Click
    If First IsNot Nothing Then
        First.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    Else
        First = New FrmFirst 
        First.MdiParent = Me
        AddHandler First.FormClosed, Sub(s, ea)
                                         First = Nothing
                                     End Sub
    End Sub
    First.Show()
End Sub
```

Now you can update the grid with the event that's fired by the second form:

```
Private Sub ToolStripLabelFrmSecond_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripLabelFrmSecond.Click
    Dim Second As New FrmSecond()
    Second.MdiParent = Me
    AddHandler Second.Start, Sub(s, ea)
                                 If First IsNot Nothing Then First.ReloadGrid()
                             End Sub
    Second.Show()
End Sub
```

Untested, should be close.